# Is there a way to exclude table name when reading from database with Pandas?

Tags: sql, database, pandas, dataframe

Whenever I use pd.read_sql() I am having the table name in front of the column name, which is really inconvenient. Is there a way to take the table name off from the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that after you read the `SQL` you end up with a `df` with columns that are named like `TABLE.COLUMN`. You can get rid of the table name quickly like this:

```
table_name = 'TABLE.'
cols = list(df.columns)
for col in cols: df = df.rename(columns=({col: col[len(table_name):]}))
```